# Why is Vigenere failing (CS50x)?

Tags: c, vigenere

OK, I'm really confused here. My pset2 Vigenere is failing the tests but when I look at the output from the test the expected outputs are exactly the same as the actual outputs. I have tried adding a \n at the end of the output and also tried removing it but nothing seems to work. Any ideas what I'm missing? I desperately want to start cleaning my code up and move on but I can't until I get he outline working.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]){

// variable declarations

if (argc != 2){
    printf("No key value was input");
    return 1; 
    }   

string key = "";
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int q = 0;
int keylen = 0;
string plaintext = "";
int plainlen = 0;

key = argv[1];
keylen = strlen(key);

for(i = 0; i <keylen; i++){
    //convert all key to lower case
    if((key[i] < 65 || key[i] > 122) || (key[i] > 90 && key[i] < 97)){
        printf("None alphabetical character detected. Exiting...");
        return 1;  }
    key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
    key[i] = key[i]-97;
    }

printf("Plaintext: ");
plaintext = get_string();   
plainlen = strlen(plaintext);
printf("ciphertext: ");

for(i = 0; i < plainlen; i++){
    if(q > plainlen){
            break;
        }
    // outer text loop
    for(j = 0; j < keylen; j++){
        if(q > plainlen){
            break;
        }
        // inner text loop

        // if we have non-alphabetic
        if((plaintext[q] < 65 || plaintext[q] > 122) || (plaintext[q] > 90 && plaintext[q] < 97)){
            printf("%c", plaintext[q]);
            //can we go negative here???
            j--;
            q++;
        }
        // check if it's wrapped
        else if(((plaintext[q]+(key[j]) > 90 && toupper(plaintext[q]) == plaintext[q])) || ((plaintext[q]+(key[j]) > 122 && tolower(plaintext[q]) == plaintext[q]))){
            printf("%c", (plaintext[q]+key[j]-26));
            q++;
        }
        // normal shift
        else{
            printf("%c", (plaintext[q]+key[j]));
            q++;
        }

    }
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to with this line `printf("Plaintext: ");`
It should be `printf("plaintext: ");`
Notice the first letter of the text to be printed is not capital.
As you yourself mentioned that your output is correct, this is the only possible mistake. Next time, check the specifications of the problem thoroughly.